# random values using CultureInfo object in C#

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I have been reviewing the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

But I still don't understand how can I randomly *retrieve* a valid 2 letter culture value using CultureInfo class such as "en" or "fr".... etc.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `new CultureInfo("en")`?

Comment: why do you want to create a random culture?

Comment: Why would you want to "randomly create a valid 2 letter culture" ? You have the complete list on that site, these all contain the information for formatting numbers, dates etc. correctly, why create a new one?

Comment: Indeed, please clarify: Do you want to *create* or *retrieve* culture information, and do you mean *randomly* (non-deterministically chosen at runtime) or *arbitrarily* (somehow chosen by you, but in a way that it works whatever you choose)?

Comment: why my question is down voted? I tried my best to message it as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm not sure exactly why you'd want this, but...) You can get a random culture by using [CultureInfo.GetCultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx), then randomly selecting from the results:

```
var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
var random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(0, allCultures.Length);

var culture = allCultures[index];

string twoLetterCode = culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

Note that this doesn't take into account that there are not an even number of cultures with the same 2 letter codes.  This will randomly pick amongst all cultures, but not evenly through the 2 letter codes.  If you want a more random distribution there, you could use:

```
var uniqueCultureCodes = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                      .Select(c => c.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();

var random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(0, uniqueCultureCodes.Count);

string twoLetterCode = uniqueCultureCodes[index];
```

This creates the distinct list of two letter codes, then randomly picks from them.

---

Edit:  If your goal is merely to create a `CultureInfo` given a two letter code such as "en" or "fr", you can do:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

Comment: thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. Its not letting me accept the answer.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner It will - you just have to wait a little while, as the system makes sure other people can answer, as well.

Comment: That's hardly random, as there is a bigger chance of getting an English culture than the German one (several "en-XX" cultures).

Comment: @SteenT It's unclear which is better - I edited to provide both options.  The original picked a random *culture* then provided the 2 letter code, my edit shows picking randomly from available 2 letter codes.

Answer (score 1):

> But I still don't understand how can I randomly create a valid 2 letter culture value using CultureInfo class such as "en" or "fr".... etc.

You mean you want to get a random culture? Simply [get all the *valid* cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx), and take a random element from that collection. (You can use [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), but be aware of the [various issues you need to handle](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx).)

EDIT: Note that if you *are* trying just to get a single culture from a known abbreviation, I'd recommend using [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540.aspx) instead of the `CultureInfo` constructor. That allows for caching, and also gives you a read-only culture which is almost certainly what you want. (It's easier to reason about read-only data...)

Comment: I think, OP means "arbitrary" when he mentions "random".

Comment: Thanks Jon.. Reed provided me the exact code that I was looking for. I am unable to accept his answer for now.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner: Please read the link in my answer about issues with `Random` though: if you call Reed's code several times in quick succession, it may well give you the same culture multiple times.

Comment: Jon.. at this point, I am not looking for true random-ness.. but I appreciate your detailed feedback.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the region (the last part of the `<language>-<region>`), you'll want to use:

```
CultureInfo[] languages = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
```

To retrieve the different languages.
If you use:

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
```

There's a bigger change of getting English than German (more English cultures than German).